# i am using below neo4j code for getting nodes and links from neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

I am using below neo4j code for getting nodes and links from neo4j database.

```
module.exports = function (resultcall){
  let neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
  let driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://192.168.1.113", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "neo4js"));


  let query = `:POST /db/data{"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH path = (n)-[r]->(m)
  RETURN path","resultDataContents":["graph","row"]}]}`;
  let session = driver.session();
  session
      .run(query)
      .then(function(result) {
          console.log(result);
          // Completed!
          session.close();
          resultcall(result);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
      });
}
```

but i am getting below error.can someone help me here

```
Structure {
  signature: 127,
  fields:
   [ { code: 'Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError',
       message: 'Invalid input \':\': expected <init> (line 1, column 1 (offset: 0))\r\n":POST /db/data{"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH p=(n)-->(m)<--(k),(n)--(k) RETURN p Limit 100","\n ^' } ] }
```

Comment: The error is showing a different Cypher statement than you show in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`run()` should be passed the Cypher statement as the first argument, and optionally an object with the parameters as the second argument. For example:

```
let query = "MATCH path = (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN path";
...
.run(query)
...
```